# normalize trained data with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lambda

this is the code from the TensorFlow website, but doesn't explain well,

```
normalization_layer = tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1./255)
train_data = train_data.map(lambda x, y: (normalization_layer(x), y)) # Where x—images, y—labels.
```

i know what is the goal of this code which is to normalize data and make it between 0 and 1 instead of 0 to 255, but I need to understand what does lambda means here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to explain I think is to see a simpler example:

```
list(map(lambda n: n * 3, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
>> [3, 6, 9, 12, 15]
```

In this case you're applying to each (because of `map`) element `n` of the list `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` the same operation `n * 3`.

In your specific case it's a bit more complicated because you have two variables. What happens is that for each `(x, y)` pair of your `train_data` you are leaving `y` as is, and applying the normalization to `x`.

**Update**, more info on what is a lambda.

This [site](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/nick/py/python-map-lambda.html) offers great examples and a good definition of lambda used inside a `map` function, like in your case:

> A lambda expression is a way of creating a little function inline,
> without all the syntax of a def. …
>
> The code of the lambda is typically a single expression without
> variables or if-statements, and does not use "return". Lambda is
> perfect where you have a short computation to write inline.

Comment: but why i have used (lambda), what is this exactly?

Comment: Ah do you mean what is a lambda? Well it’s just an anonymous function: a function that has no name and it is executed right where you define it. See the [docs](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/lambda.html) for a more detailed definition.

Comment: I’ve updated the answer to add more info on lambdas. `lambda` is just a keyword for indicating the start to the… lambda

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming `train_data` is a `tf.dataset`

Each element inside a `tf.dataset` is stored in the form of a tuple of `X` and `y` values like this `(X,y)`.

To access say, each element in a tuple in python, you can do

```
for X,y in tuple_list:
    print(X)
    print(y)
```

This is essentially what `map` with `lambda` does in the `tf.dataset`

This is what happens inside the map function

- x-images of train data is assigned x
- y-labels of train data is assigned y
- You create a new tuple where x becomes `normalization_layer(x)`and y stays `y`
- This is done for every example in `train_data`
- This is fed back and stored in `train_data` (Since you are overwriting the variable)

See [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/lambda-function-in-python-example-syntax/) for more information on how the Lambda function generally works in Python. Would specifically draw attention to general lambda syntax

```
lambda args: expression
```